# how to chain xpath with css selector in selenium?

Tags: html, css, selenium-webdriver, xpath

There is an element I want to select in selenium automation script.
The approach I used was to narrow down the element with CSS and then select the element of interest with text using XPath.

HTML:-

```
<div data-testid="Tabs" class="compact-tab ccTabsView">
<div class="ui pointing secondary menu">
    <a class="active item">Text 1</a>
    <a class="item">Text 2</a></div>
<div class="ui segment active tab">
    <div class="tabContainer tabContainerCC"></div>
</div>
```

selector:-

```
$webDriver.wait($selenium.until.elementLocated($selenium.By.css(".compact-tab.ccTabsView").xpath("//*[text()='Text 2']")), defaultTimeout);
```

but it seems we can't chain the XPath with CSS sector. as this is throwing the error.

`$selenium.By.css(...).xpath is not a function`

I don't want to use the CSS class under the parent div because those are added by the library.

What is the correct way to select such element?

Comment: Are you sure that `$selenium.By.css()` returns a WedElement object? Maybe you need something like `$webDriver.wait($selenium.until.elementLocated($selenium.By.css(".compact-tab.ccTabsView")), defaultTimeout).xpath("//*[text()='Text 2']")`? Also it's better to add a programming-language tag as well